# Why does my React App have a syntax error for index.pack.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my code in the index.html. It's just a simple create-react-app and I added some script tags for firebase. Not sure why the index.pack.js script tag is saying a syntax error for some reason.

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8" />
          <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
          <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
          <meta
            name="description"
            content="Web site created using create-react-app"
          />
          <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
          <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.16.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
          <!--
            manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
            user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
          -->
          <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
          <!--
            Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
            It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
            Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

            Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
            work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
            Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
          -->
          <title>React App</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript> 
          <div id="root"></div>
          <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.4/firebase-auth.js"></script>
          <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.4/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
          <script src="/src/index.pack.js"></script>
          <!--
            This HTML file is a template.
            If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

            You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
            The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

            To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
            To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
          -->
        </body>
      </html>
```

This line right here is saying there's an error and I don't know how to fix the code since it's a script tag and supposedly it's reading it wrong

```
 <script src="/src/index.pack.js"></script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are missing . at the beginning of path.

```
 <script src="/src/index.pack.js"></script>
```

Should be

```
 <script src="./src/index.pack.js"></script>
```

Comment: that's not the issue. It didn't change anything

Comment: Check that the path is correct and there is index.pack.js file in src directory. Also the file name has .pack.js as extension so it might not be seen as a script file. Change it to index_pack.js or something else.  c

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, did you ever figure it out?